# How to add time taken in a quiz using laravel 5.1 and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, timer

I got stacked with this for 3 days, so I really need your help. Here we go, I want to implement a time getter or manager in my `laravel5.1` application.

**What I have:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var d;
  setInterval(function(){
    d = new Date();
    dates = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':' + d.getSeconds();
    $('#timeTaken').val(dates);
  }, 1000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" id="timeTaken" value="">
```

**What is the problem:**

The scenario is, I already have this code above when I started the quiz. The problem is, if the user take the quiz, there are two buttons there where they can choose to just `save` what they done, or to `submit` the quiz. Now...

---

**What I want:**

**1**. Get the date/time when the quiz started. (I already have this one)

**2**. I need a timer that count the time taken by the user. *Note: Quiz sometimes has time limit, sometimes unlimited time*, but if the user want to save it for a while, the timer stop, and the user can continue the quiz later with the `time left` saved in the database.

**3**. Get the time taken by the user, for example `21 days 1 hour` or `1 min 51 secs` or `7 days 17 hours`, etc.

**Note:**

I don't want to use `cookies` as it can be deleted through the browser.

Comment: Is this timer to outlive the browser tab?

Comment: Not necessary . We can just put the timer on the page.

Comment: Then it's as simple as getting the current time when "save" is triggered, and subtracting the old time from the new time. Formatting time has been answered in other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Ok then, I'm gonna try it